# Define a variable on a Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the `View`s of my code, I am used to the following examples:

```
//for functions
functionName: function(…){…},
//for objects
objectName: function(…){…},
//for returning a function
nameToReturnFunction: function(…){ return {…} },
```

How would I write the following, not in the render() or init()?

```
    var pathFunction = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function (d) {return d.x;})
      .y(function (d) {return d.y;})
      .interpolate('basis'); // bundle | basis | linear | cardinal are also options
```

I have declared the variable in the render or init and then used `this.pathFunction = pathFunction;`, but since there are no parameters, I think it should be on the `View` as a whole.

In the various places I need to call `pathFunction`, I would like to refer to it as `this.pathFunction`.   I tried the following:

```
pathFunction: function() {
    var pathFunction = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function (d) {return d.x;})
      .y(function (d) {return d.y;})
      .interpolate('basis');    
}
```

but this didn't work, as `this.pathFunction` is a function that doesn't return what the variable call does when I do `.attr('d', pathFunction)` as previously structured.

Comment: Could you add a little more explanation on what you mean by "how do I attach this variable function chain to the View as part of itself."

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with the d3 api, but the following should work:

```
pathFunction: function() {
    return d3.svg.line()
      .x(function (d) {return d.x;})
      .y(function (d) {return d.y;})
      .interpolate('basis');    
}
```

Which you should then be able to call as before: `.attr('d', pathFunction)`.

Your current snippet was executing the d3 function properly, but only within the scope of pathFunction (which did not return it to the calling function).